# Add default first option as select element when populating select options from an enum field in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

`enum` field is defined as:

```cs
public enum HasSomething
{
    Installed_by_Installer,
    Not_Installed_by_Installer,
    Not_Present
}
```

I'm trying to add this to options in a `select` element as following:

```html
<select asp-for="HasSomething" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<HasSomething>()" class="form-control">
    <option selected hidden>---Select---</option>
</select>
```

The first option `---Select---` is missing out. So first value `Installed by Installer` automatically becomes the selected value on post which is obviously a wrong input. Can someone please guide how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work it's necessary to define your model property to be nullable and set it to `null`.

Let say the view model is declared like:

```cs
public class MyModel
{     
    public HasSomething? Something { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in the view use:

```html
@model MyModel

<select class="form-control"
        asp-for="Something"
        asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<HasSomething>()">
    <option selected>---Select---</option>
</select>
```

Perhaps you need to add the `<Nullable>` directive to the project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  ...   
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

Another solution is to use the `Display` attribute and add an additional option to the `enum` values. Then not necessary to define the `<option selected>---Select---</option>`. The `Unassigned` value might be set by default.

```cs
public enum HasSomething
{
    [Display(Name = "---Select---")]
    Unassigned,
    [Display(Name = "Installed by Installer")]
    Installed_by_Installer,
    [Display(Name = "Not Installed by Installer")]
    Not_Installed_by_Installer,
    [Display(Name = "Not Present")]
    Not_Present
}

public class MyModel
{     
    public HasSomething? Something { get; set; } = HasSomething.Unassigned;
}
```

Comment: Declaring `public HasSomething? Something { get; set; } ` worked.  Good job. Thanks